# Array sorting based on sort number in another array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, angular, typescript

I want to sort and rearrange the **widgets** array based on sort_number in **widgetOrder** array.
I have tried looping widgets array for coomparing sort_number in widgetOrder. This widget array represents the items on an Admin panel dashboard page.It has tiles called widgets that will be able to change it's position or showing order. When the position of a tile is changed ,it is pushed to widgetOrder.!

```
const widgets =
                    [
                        {
                            id: 59,
                            roleId: 3,
                            widgetId: 1,
                            sort_number: 1,
                            created_by: '1',
                            updated_by: '1',
                            createdAt: '2021 - 04 - 22T03: 09: 32.098Z',
                            updatedAt: '2021 - 04 - 22T03: 09: 32.098Z',
                            'dashboardWidget.id': 1,
                            'dashboardWidget.name': 'bookingCount',
                            'dashboardWidget.displayName': 'Booking Count',
                            'dashboardWidget.description': 'Shows the count of total bookings for the time period if specified, otherwise shows all booking count',
                            'dashboardWidget.isCounter': 1
                        },
                        {
                            id: 60,
                            roleId: 3,
                            widgetId: 2,
                            sort_number: 2,
                            created_by: '1',
                            updated_by: '1',
                            createdAt: '2021 - 04 - 22T03: 09: 32.098Z',
                            updatedAt: '2021 - 04 - 22T03: 09: 32.098Z',
                            'dashboardWidget.id': 2,
                            'dashboardWidget.name': 'pickUpCount',
                            'dashboardWidget.displayName': 'Pick-up Count',
                            'dashboardWidget.description': 'Shows the count of total pick-ups for the time period if specified, otherwise shows all pick-up count',
                            'dashboardWidget.isCounter': 1
                        },
                        {
                            id: 61,
                            roleId: 3,
                            widgetId: 3,
                            sort_number: 3,
                            created_by: '1',
                            updated_by: '1',
                            createdAt: '2021 - 04 - 22T03: 09: 32.098Z',
                            updatedAt: '2021 - 04 - 22T03: 09: 32.098Z',
                            'dashboardWidget.id': 3,
                            'dashboardWidget.name': 'dropOutCount',
                            'dashboardWidget.displayName': 'Drop-out Count',
                            'dashboardWidget.description': 'Shows the count of total drop-outs for the time period if specified, otherwise shows all drop-out count',
                            'dashboardWidget.isCounter': 1
                        },
                        {
                            id: 62,
                            roleId: 3,
                            widgetId: 9,
                            sort_number: 4,
                            created_by: '1',
                            updated_by: '1',
                            createdAt: '2021 - 04 - 22T03: 09: 32.098Z',
                            updatedAt: '2021 - 04 - 22T03: 09: 32.098Z',
                            'dashboardWidget.id': 9,
                            'dashboardWidget.name': 'enquiryCount',
                            'dashboardWidget.displayName': 'Enquiry Count',
                            'dashboardWidget.description': 'Shows the count of total enquires for the time period if specified, otherwise shows all enquiry count',
                            'dashboardWidget.isCounter': 1
                        }
                    ];              

const widgetOrder =  [
                            { widgetId: 2, sort_number: 4, is_visible: 1 },
                            { widgetId: 3, sort_number: 1, is_visible: 1 }
                          ];
```

Comment: What would be your final expected result?

Comment: What about the elements doesn't have any sorting order,

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind redefining the widgets array this might come in handy:

```
const orderedWidgets = [];
widgetOrder.sort((a,b) => a.sortNumber - b.sortNumber);
for (const orderItem of widgetOrder) {
  const foundWidget = widgets.find((widget) => widget.id === orderItem.id);
  if (foundWidget) {
    orderedWidgets.push(foundWidget);
  }
}
// You'll need to make widgets a variable for this to work:
widgets = orderedWidgets
```

This is the simplest solution I have in mind since Array.sort() requires to comparable elements from the same array to work.
If you need to keep your widgets array persistent, please reply and I will try to help.

Answer (score 1):

If any element that is not in `widgetOrder` then they will push at the last of the array.

```js
const widgets = [
  {
    id: 59,
    roleId: 3,
    widgetId: 1,
    sort_number: 1,
    created_by: "1",
    updated_by: "1",
    createdAt: "2021 - 04 - 22T03: 09: 32.098Z",
    updatedAt: "2021 - 04 - 22T03: 09: 32.098Z",
    "dashboardWidget.id": 1,
    "dashboardWidget.name": "bookingCount",
    "dashboardWidget.displayName": "Booking Count",
    "dashboardWidget.description":
      "Shows the count of total bookings for the time period if specified, otherwise shows all booking count",
    "dashboardWidget.isCounter": 1,
  },
  {
    id: 60,
    roleId: 3,
    widgetId: 2,
    sort_number: 2,
    created_by: "1",
    updated_by: "1",
    createdAt: "2021 - 04 - 22T03: 09: 32.098Z",
    updatedAt: "2021 - 04 - 22T03: 09: 32.098Z",
    "dashboardWidget.id": 2,
    "dashboardWidget.name": "pickUpCount",
    "dashboardWidget.displayName": "Pick-up Count",
    "dashboardWidget.description":
      "Shows the count of total pick-ups for the time period if specified, otherwise shows all pick-up count",
    "dashboardWidget.isCounter": 1,
  },
  {
    id: 61,
    roleId: 3,
    widgetId: 3,
    sort_number: 3,
    created_by: "1",
    updated_by: "1",
    createdAt: "2021 - 04 - 22T03: 09: 32.098Z",
    updatedAt: "2021 - 04 - 22T03: 09: 32.098Z",
    "dashboardWidget.id": 3,
    "dashboardWidget.name": "dropOutCount",
    "dashboardWidget.displayName": "Drop-out Count",
    "dashboardWidget.description":
      "Shows the count of total drop-outs for the time period if specified, otherwise shows all drop-out count",
    "dashboardWidget.isCounter": 1,
  },
  {
    id: 62,
    roleId: 3,
    widgetId: 9,
    sort_number: 4,
    created_by: "1",
    updated_by: "1",
    createdAt: "2021 - 04 - 22T03: 09: 32.098Z",
    updatedAt: "2021 - 04 - 22T03: 09: 32.098Z",
    "dashboardWidget.id": 9,
    "dashboardWidget.name": "enquiryCount",
    "dashboardWidget.displayName": "Enquiry Count",
    "dashboardWidget.description":
      "Shows the count of total enquires for the time period if specified, otherwise shows all enquiry count",
    "dashboardWidget.isCounter": 1,
  },
];

const widgetOrder = [
  { widgetId: 2, sort_number: 4, is_visible: 1 },
  { widgetId: 3, sort_number: 1, is_visible: 1 },
];

let result = [];
const temp = [];

widgets.forEach((widget) => {
  const order = widgetOrder.find((o) => o.widgetId === widget.widgetId)?.sort_number;
  if (order) result[order] = widget;
  else temp.push(widget);
});

result = [...result.filter((w) => w), ...temp];
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a function to help me get the sort number from widgetOrder

```
const getSortNumber = (widgetOrder, id) => {
    var orderEle = widgetOrder.filter((ele) => ele['widgetId']===id)[0]
  
  //if no sorting order return 0
  return orderEle? orderEle['sort_number'] : 0
}
```

Then I use the .sort() and the function to sort widgets based on their IDs
For ascending/descending just swap a and b in the getSortNumber parameters

```
widgets = widgets.sort((a,b) => getSortNumber(widgetOrder, b['widgetId']) - getSortNumber(widgetOrder, a['widgetId']))
```